# Issue with Emscripten installation on mac

Tags: python, c++, macos, webassembly, emscripten

this is my first time diving into emscripten and web assembly and I am having some trouble with the installation process. I tried following the directions for mac on emscriptens website and I am able to do the pull command from github with no problem. However when trying to install emscripten with the "./emsdk install latest" command line it keeps failing.

Been at this for hours and I have updated just about everything and re-downloaded python to make sure it is the newest version. This is the error message I am getting:

Error: Downloading URL 'https://storage.googleapis.com/webassembly/emscripten-releases-builds/deps/node-v14.18.2-darwin-x64.tar.gz': <urlopen error [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate (_ssl.c:997)>
Warning: Possibly SSL/TLS issue. Update or install Python SSL root certificates (2048-bit or greater) supplied in Python folder or https://pypi.org/project/certifi/ and try again.
error: installation failed!

Any help is much appreciated! Thank you!

Comment: You do not have an emscripten problem. Most likely the root certificates are not installed, out of date, or not accessible. Start here: https://pypi.org/project/certifi/ and try to understand what that package does to help you figure out the solution. Your question does not have enough details on how your system is configured to know what the exact issue is.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please do not use python2. Install certifi with pip3 install certifi. Then just browse to Applications/Python 3.x and double-click Install Certificates.command

Now you can continue the installation.

Answer (score 0):

Do not use Python 3. You must use Python 2.

<s>`python3 ./emsdk.py install latest`</s>
<s>`python3 ./emsdk.py activate latest`</s>

```
python ./emsdk.py install latest
python ./emsdk.py activate latest
```

See also [Unable to install latest due to SSL certificate verify failed](https://github.com/emscripten-core/emscripten/issues/9036) and [Emsdk download fails on clean-is macOS Catalina 10.15.1](https://github.com/emscripten-core/emsdk/issues/406)